# keras example Type Error

Tags: keras

I installed WinPython and Keras 0.1.2 in my Win64 System, then I started to run the examples provided in Keras source code floder, but lots errors occured make me frustrated - -!

Somebody help me, thanks for any tips.

I try to run 'mnist_mlp.py', but an error occured in the line blow:

```
    model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(784,)))
    TypeError:__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_shape'
```

then I find the examples on http://keras.io/examples/
and when I run to the line below I still faced some error.

```
    model.add(Dense(20, 64, init='uniform'))
    TypeError:__init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'init'
```

[Keras Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhBK8.png)

Comment: I just experienced a similar issue, although with a different argument and in version 1.0.6. Nevertheless updating to 1.1.1 from git solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples http://keras.io/examples/ have not been updated after the recent API changes https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/keras-users/iWVrWpR_eaQ.

Make sure you have the latest version of Keras installed with:

```
sudo pip install git+git://github.com/fchollet/keras.git --upgrade
```

and use updated examples from the same repository https://github.com/fchollet/keras/tree/master/examples

Comment: I tried this and solved it, the examples is not synchronize with the API is really wired. Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0):

As of 19th November, the latest version of Keras 0.2.0 isn't what you do `pip install`. You'll need to download it from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Keras. After extracting the files, run `python setup.py install`

Comment: Thank you so much for you advices~